# Grails v3.0.17 Project Runnig fine in linux but unable to build in mac os

Tags: macos, gradle, grails, groovy

I have a grails project version 3 and it is running absolutly fine on intellij ide  v 2018.3.6 in linux os but same project when i try to run on mac os its build is getting failed.

**Grails version 3.0.17 and
Intellij Idea version 2018.3.6 and Groovy Version: 2.4.5**

```
gradle-wrapper.properties of my project
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip
```

whenever i try to build this project using ./gradlew build this is the error i am getting

```
:compileGroovy
/Users/tom/ptoject/code/grailsTestProject/build/tmp/compileGroovy/groovy-java-stubs/com/example/util/Test.java:12: error: cannot access Test
  extends com.example.util.vo.Test  implements
                             ^
  bad source file: /Users/tom/ptoject/code/grailsTestProject/build/tmp/compileGroovy/groovy-java-stubs/com/example/util/Test.java
    file does not contain class com.examle.util.Test
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
startup failed:
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
1 error
:compileGroovy FAILED
```

This `extends com.example.util.vo.Test`  class is a common class for multiple projects so i declared this in a separate java project and using it as a jar on different projects

Now i think this jar is creating issue in mac

Comment: "file does not contain class com.examle.util.Test" (instead of correctly spelled example) and/or Test.java.java (double .java) seem like possible candidates for your problems.

Comment: sorry that  is typing mistake

Comment: Can you show the source code for your `Test` class, including the `package` statement, and indicate where that source file is in your workspace?

Comment: One possible explanation for the error message is a mistaken `package` statement and the error message above looks to have been copied and pasted from an actual error log.  Is it possible that the package name has a mistake in your source code?  The error message includes "file does not contain class com.examle.util.Test" (notice `example` vs `example`)

Comment: I have tried to recreate this issue and I cannot.  If you can file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and link to a simple sample app which demonstrates the issue, we will investigate.  Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Sir that example is just a spelling or typing mistake actually the same project is running fine in linux machine but its build is getting failed in Macbook

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have updated the question please have a look on it

Comment: Whenever i am trying to extends some class from my common jar in this grails project its build is getting failed

Comment: "Whenever i am trying to extends some class from my common jar in this grails project its build is getting failed" - That is good info and may help reproduce the problem.  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Your edit still includes "`file does not contain class com.examle.util.Test`".  That looks like a genuine error message that the system generated and you copied and pasted.  Is it, or is that a message that was typed by hand and that is where the typo came from?